# GCC: conflicting optimizations

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Due to long build times, I haven't been able to sufficiently narrow down the culprit leading to `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault` (I have managed to rule out LTO, though). Present in GCC versions 4.8.2, 4.8.3, and 4.9.1, rather than a bug I'm suspecting a conflict between the remaining various optimization strategies:

Generic: most likely unrelated, here for completeness

- -pipe
- -march=native
- -O3
- -msse2
- -mfpmath=sse
- -ffast-math

Graphite: loop optimization with regard to memory access

- -floop-interchange
- -floop-strip-mine
- -floop-block

Graphite: not really sure

- -fgraphite-identity

ISL: loop optimizations with regard to memory access and automatic parallelism

- -floop-nest-optimize

Graphite: loop optimization with regard to automatic parallelism

- -floop-parallelize-all
- -ftree-parallelize-loops=2

Sets of options seem to share significant functional overlap. If this has likely been leading to the segmentation fault during compilation, which options should I preserve and which should I cull in order to maximize performance?

Comment: Try building with `-pipe -march=native -O2` and see if that works.  If it does, try `-O3` and then add on whatever you want after that until it breaks again.  And please don't tell us your build times are so long you can't do this...if your build times are that long then you probably don't really need so many esoteric options.  :)

Comment: The segfault is when you run the compiler, not when you run your code, insn't it ?

Comment: @Christophe oh sry, my bad

Comment: No matter what options you give, the compiler should not segfault. If possible, trim down your code until it's small and report it to the gcc folks. Once you have reported it, you may get some suggestions on how to work around it...

Answer (score 0):

Finally narrowed the segfault down to the `-ffast-math` and `-floop-parallelize-all` options, exclusively. This issue is identical to [[4.8/4.9 Regression] [graphite] Segmentation fault with -Ofast -floop-paralle...](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59586), and should be fixed upstream. Since the fix was pushed Jun 29, while gcc 4.9.1 was released Jul 16 it was branched in Apr, it is not included in the 4.8.3 and 4.9.1 releases.